# Plot a Graph MATLAB Cell String Array vs Double

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, line, axis

I am having a cell string array

t=({'03:00:10.000' '03:00:20.000' '03:00:30.000'});

this is actually a time array representing HH:MM:SS

and

Double numeric number array representation voltages values

b=[231.098,231.145,231.032]

now i want to draw a simple graph please help me....

Comment: I have actually 360 samples of time in one hour..                                       t=({'03:00:10.000' '03:00:20.000' '03:00:30.000..........04:00:00.000'});    and 360 voltage  value b=[231.098,231.145,231.032..........235.032]     now when i am drawing the graph the x-axis 360 values are too much and it makes my graph very difficult to read x-axis... is it possible to increase the step size like any function which takes automatically t vector values on x-axis but just show like only 5 to six values for example  03:00:10     03:15:00   03:30:00   03:45:00  04:00:00 even

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you are just talking about those 3 values or asking for a general way to plot values vs timestamps in general. For the first case:

```
figurehandle = figure; % you wont need the figurehandle but just in case
axeshandle = axes; % you wont need that as well but it is nicer to code with this
plot(axeshandle,b);
axeshandle.XTick=[1 2 3];
axeshandle.XTickLabel=t;
```

a lot of this code can be made more general if you need it pls comment what you need
also if you dont need any of that extra handles and a shorter code

```
plot(b)
set(gca,'XTick',[1 2 3]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',t);
```

the 'Xtick' argument determines the x values where the Ticks are placed and the 'XtickLabel' determines what every label says, so in the case of 360 data values:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[1 60 120 180 240 300 360]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',t([1 60 120 180 240 300 360]));
```

also you are not bound to using the labels of the t vector if you dont want to you might as well use

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',['3' '3:10' '3:20' 'half past 3' '3:40' '3:50' '4']);
```

you can get everything you want there (even latex specials), but the number of entries has to be the same as the number of tick choosen by 'XTick'. If its not about the coding for you and just about making one nice graph you might use the 'show plot tools and dock figure'-button on the matlab plot window (usually the last of the lower button-bar where you can change pretty much everything about the plot in a nice toolbox

Comment: I have actually 360 samples of time in one hour..                                       t=({'03:00:10.000' '03:00:20.000' '03:00:30.000..........04:00:00.000'});    and 360 voltage  value b=[231.098,231.145,231.032..........235.032]     now when i am drawing the graph the x-axis 360 values are too much and it makes my graph very difficult to read x-axis... is it possible to increase the step size like any function which takes automatically t vector values on x-axis but just show like only 5 to six values for example  03:00:10     03:15:00   03:30:00   03:45:00  04:00:00 even

Answer (score 0):

You should use plot for drawing. Try this:

```
plot(t, b);
```